# fontenc vs fontspec with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, font-encodings

I have encountered something I fail to understand. I have read that I should use fontspec and not fontenc when I use XeLaTeX, but this causes some problems for me when I use the cochineal font package.

When I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal} 

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    some text
\end{document}
```

I get the message in the log that `Font shape TU/Cochineal-OsF/m/n undefined(Font) using TU/lmr/m/n instead` and the font for the title defaults ot Latin Modern. But when I instead use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal} 

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    some text
\end{document}
```

I don't get that message and the title is in the Cochineal font. Am I setting something wrong when I use fontspec? Is there some drawback with using fontenc together with XeLaTex? I would really like to get Cochineal also in the title.

I'm using MikTex on a Windows 10 machine.

All the best,
Richard

Comment: this font is not suited for xelatex/lualatex.

Comment: Thank you, it looks ok even though I use xelatex, is there some problem with using xelatex and cochineal? Is there some similar font that is a better option (if I have to stick to xelatex)?

Comment: Type `Grüße` in your example with fontenc and you will see the problem. T1/fontenc is not for xelatex. It will break with quite a number of chars. Use pdflatex if you want to use your font.

Comment: if you use T1 encoding then 8bit encoded fonts will appear to load but all hyphenation will be wrong as the hyphenation tables loaded for xelatex assume Unicode.

Comment: I tried Grüße and it worked just fine, but are there other problems that some characters will break? I'm using a university template that is made for xelatex, so it would be much easier if I could stick to it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, that doesn't sound good. Thank you! If I use fontspec and cochineal, could I run into other problems than that the title doesn't come out in the correct font? Sorry about all these questions, I'm new to Latex.

Comment: but the fonts are available as OpenType so you can use them directly with xetex and fontspec https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cochineal/opentype

Comment: so it looks like you just need the fonts (but not the package )

Comment: That seems much easier, I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: If Grüße worked fine you didn't try it in your fontenc example ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cochineal` package is only for `pdflatex`. If you have installed the OpenType version of Cochineal as a system font you can emulate the package as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Cochineal}[
  Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},
]
\setmainlanguage{english}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlf}{\lfstyle}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tlfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Tabular,Lining}}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttlf}{\tlfstyle}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

some text 1234567890\par
some text {\lfstyle 1234567890} \textlf{1234567890}\par
some text {\tlfstyle 1234567890} \texttlf{1234567890}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reasons, you only rely on the TeX Live distribution, the font setup is slightly different.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Cochineal}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Roman,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},
]
\setmainlanguage{english}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlf}{\lfstyle}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tlfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Tabular,Lining}}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttlf}{\tlfstyle}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

some text 1234567890\par
some text {\lfstyle 1234567890} \textlf{1234567890}\par
some text {\tlfstyle 1234567890} \texttlf{1234567890}\par

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With xetex you want to use the default TU (Unicode) encoding and access the OpenType versions of the font directly via `fontspec`

[image]

The pdffonts utility confirms that the font used in the pdf is:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
FXMMJJ+Cochineal-Roman-Identity-H    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

This from a source of

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cochineal}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    some text
\end{document}
```